# How to stop Minecraft from Auto-Signing me in?

Tags: minecraft-education-edition

I am playing Minecraft Education Edition and when I try to sign in it doesn't even let me type anything, it just auto signs me in, and when it does it says we cannot connect to internet. Is there a way to stop it from automatically signing me in?

Device information:

- Google Chrome OS
- Version 94.0.4606.114 (Official Build) (64-bit)

video to explain-

Comment: Maybe this is a bit too obvious for someone to overlook, but are you sure you're connected to the internet when you open the program...?

Comment: yes i am it's just glishing

Comment: I saw your previous post - and thank you for deleting it and instead editing this one.  However, it looks like your video is not working.  You may want to upload it to something else (like YouTube) and post a link to that instead.

Comment: @TimmyJim thanks i did :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could "reset" all settings, when you yust remove or rename the minecraft save directory.

Open `%appdata%\` in your explorer (on windows it sends you to "c:\Users\YourUsername\AppData\Roaming"). In this directory you should find a `.minecraft` folder, this usually contains all your userdata.

Yust remove or rename this folder, and all you "old" minecraft settings should be removed, and you should be able to enter your logindata when you start the game again.

Comment: I am sorry but as i said in my question I have a chromebook not windows.

Comment: Okay, but the env-variable `%appdata%` should even exist there, but maybe pointing to another directory. Can you yust check what happens if you try to switch directory to `%appdata%` ?

Comment: @circusbaby23
Or yust follow this video to find the `.minecraft`-folder. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gMzEPipBL_w

Comment: @Radon8472: `%foo%` is a Windows-ism, you can't use that syntax on non-Windows systems.

Comment: @Radon8472 tnaks so much take the bounty you earned it